# Merging objects of class "factor" on R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, levels

I have four `data.frames` (`DATA1`, `DATA2`, `DATA3` and `DATA4`)

I'm interested in accessing one particular variable, which is common for every `data.frame`:
`DATA1$Point`
`DATA2$Point`
`DATA3$Point`
`DATA4$Point`

```
class(DATA1$Point)
[1] "factor"`
```

**I want to merge the levels of each `data.frame` object in a single object**

Something like:

```
TOTAL_POINTS <- merge(DATA1$Point,DATA2$Point,DATA3$Point,DATA4$Point)
```

But, obviously, it doesn't work.

I wanna know which `Points` were visited, taking in consideration all of the `data.frames` objects.

How can I do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge` would be the wrrong function. Just use `factor( unlist(. ))`, but only after converting the individual factor vectors to character first since they may have different levels attributes:

```
 TOTAL_POINTS<-factor(  unlist ( lapply( list( DATA1$Point,
                                        DATA2$Point,
                                        DATA3$Point,
                                        DATA4$Point) ,
                                  as.character)
                      ) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. but the `factor`function seems to be misbehaving in the code you sent me:
`> factor(c(lapply(list(Hylo$Point,Hypo$Point,Lipa$Point,Rampho$Point),as.character)))
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?`

Comment: Maybe replace `c` with `unlist`? I will remind you that you did not offer a test case.

Comment: @Mohr - keep in mind that we have no clue what you're working with.  It's hard to diagnose a problem that you can't see. Perhaps provide a small bit of your data.

Comment: Sorry...I'm very beginner level. Will try to make things better next time.